# Android - Map View Controller

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I am first time implementing Google Map in Android and troubling to show "View Controller" in Android.

Let me clear about my problem: **`I want to display the "View Controller" which shows different view button, such as Satellite, street View, Hybrid, etc.`** So how do i show the "View controller" in Google map with Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the following options to your MapView to define which mode to display.

```
mapView.setSatellite(true);
mapView.setStreetView(true);
```

But there are no buttons by default as part of the MapView that you can display to the user. This you could implement with embedding the MapView and the buttons into a `FrameLayout`, so that the buttons are floating on top of the map.

Comment: @Mathias Lin thanx for the answer and ya i know this , but is it not possible to dispay view copntroller as we are looking with general google map ?

Comment: with 'view controller' you mean the buttons, as in the Google Maps WEB version, right? cause a MapView also has a MapController, but it has a different meaning.
If you look at the Google Maps App on Android (not the Google Maps on the Web), you also won't see any buttons there for satellite, street view, etc. - these options are also only available there via the context menu.
There are no buttons by default as part of the MapView that you can display.

Comment: @Mathias Lin ya you got exactly, want to display buttons as in the Google Maps Web version..but i have developed the button as the samee way you have mentioned

Comment: @Mathis Lin Have you marked that "Satellite view in Android" is the "Hybrid view in I-phone", i mean to say "Satellite view in I-phone" showing only satellite view without city name or other name..

Comment: @Mathias is it possible to display only "Satellite map" without name of city, state, etc. ?? how do i display it ?? thanx for your such support

Comment: I'm not familiar with the iPhone Maps, don't have/use iPhone. Not sure if/how to remove city names, in fact I havent' used satellite mode  much.